# Parsing a password to an integer

Tags: java, swing, jpasswordfield

This is code for reading a text field in Java Swing

```
jbtLogin.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    String id=jtfId.getText();      

    String s=new String(jpass.getPassword());
    int password = Integer.parseInt(s);
```

But I have this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input     string: ""
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: your string might be empty or contains characters other than digits.

Comment: The error says that you can't convert an empty string to an `int`. You have to check this before.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701520/java-lang-numberformatexception-for-input-string)

Comment: also check this, to check if your input is numeric. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102891/how-to-check-if-a-string-is-numeric-in-java/1102916#1102916

Comment: 1) `String s=new String(jpass.getPassword());` A password should never be turned into a `String` as it becomes a security weakness. 2) And `int password = Integer.parseInt(s);` allowing 'only integers' in a password is another security weakness. In general, passwords should enforce that they contain numeric, lower ***&*** upper case letters.

Comment: [This is why you shouldn't convert the `char[]` value return by `JPasswordField` to a `String`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881291/why-is-char-preferred-over-string-for-passwords) - this real question is, why are you expecting an `int`?